# Send.php not showing content of the forms

Tags: php

so i finally got my feedback form to be working and sending emails to my email address but i have another problem. The content of the forms are not showing, don't know what is wrong. I'm new to php tho so i'm very sure its simple.. posted the code below

```
<?php 
 $name = $_POST ['name'];
 $mail = $_POST ['mail'];
 $number = $_POST ['number'];
 $feedback = $_POST ['feedback'];

 $to = 'ATotallyRandom@Email.net';
 $subject = 'Feedback from atetaconsult.com';
 $msg = "Your name: $name\n" .
 " Your email: $email\n" .
 " Feedback: $feedback\n";

 mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

 echo ' thank you <br/>';
 echo ' your name ' .$name .'<br/>';
 echo ' Your email ' . $email .'<br/>';
 echo ' Your feedback ' . $feedback . '<br/>';

 ?>
```

The HTML code for the form is below too

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <p class="head" style="font-style: italic; color: #fff; line-height: 24px; font-size: 19px; margin-bottom: 47px; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Lato, sans-serif;">
                We’d love to hear from you. Interested in working together? Fill out the form below with some info about your project and I will get back to you as soon as I can. Please allow a couple days for me to respond.</p>
    <div class="row form">
        <input id="name" class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input id="mail" class="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input id="number" class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="span6 box box_r">
        <textarea id="feedback" rows="6" class="span6" placeholder="Type a message here..."></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="btn" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Send your message">
    </div>
  </form><div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html code of the form?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` to see if values are actually passed through form

Comment: What do you mean by the "content of the form"? Do you want that the form to persist what the user just sent to your email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$msg = "Your name: $name\n" .
" Your email: $email\n" .
 " Feedback: $feedback\n";
```

you are asking for the variable $email

but you have specified it as $mail at the top.

See: http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/StackOverflow/phpmail.php?name=Mark&mail=test@test.com&feedback=testfeedback

I have changed it to $email and the type to $_GET for demonstration purposes, but it seems to be working. Try that.

Here is the Full code for the file:

```
<?php 
 $name = $_GET ['name'];
 $email = $_GET ['mail'];
 $number = $_GET ['number'];
 $feedback = $_GET ['feedback'];

 $to = 'ATotallyRandom@Email.net';
 $subject = 'Test from Mark P';
 $msg = "Your name: $name\n";
 $msg .= " Your email: $email\n";
 $msg .= " Feedback: $feedback\n";

 mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

 echo ' thank you <br/>';
 echo ' your name ' .$name .'<br/>';
 echo ' Your email ' . $email .'<br/>';
 echo ' Your feedback ' . $feedback . '<br/>';

 ?>
 <br /><br />
 Here is the result from $msg: <br /><br />
 <?php 

 echo $msg;

 ?>
```

You need to add name into your html:

```
    <input name="name" id="name" class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input name="mail" id="mail" class="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input name="number" id="number" class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
```

Comment: I've just tested it with my email. Seems to be working. I will send it to yours and see what happens. ! sec

Comment: Just realised that the email in there is fake so you wont get it. lol.

Comment: check my edit. I fixed your HTML and your wrong variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

Put all these code in between:

```
if($_POST){

// Your coding

}
```

Also show me the Javascript/Jquery coding you are using on contact form.

Comment: This does not solve anything. `$_POST` is always defined. Did you mean `if(empty($_POST))`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set a name value on the input.

Change in:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <p class="head" style="font-style: italic; color: #fff; line-height: 24px; font-size: 19px; margin-bottom: 47px; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Lato, sans-serif;">
                We’d love to hear from you. Interested in working together? Fill out the form below with some info about your project and I will get back to you as soon as I can. Please allow a couple days for me to respond.</p>
    <div class="row form">
        <input name="name" id="name" class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input name="mail" id="mail" class="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input name="number" id="number" class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="span6 box box_r">
        <textarea name="feedback" id="feedback" rows="6" class="span6" placeholder="Type a message here..."></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="btn" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Send your message">
    </div>
  </form><div style="clear: both;"></div>
```